# React query used multiple times in same component

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a component that contains a select (drop down) with multiselect, and each time a new item is selected i want to fetch data related to the value using react query and append this data to my state model of all selected values. However, currently i can't see how this is done using react query, as my `useQuery` needs to be created with the id to fetch defined already.

In short - how can i keep fetching object defined by an key using react query on the same component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a good use-case for the [useQueries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQueries) hook. Given your selection that is likely an Array of some sort, you can map over that and fire off multiple requests. Then, you'll get a result array with all the responses of all the selected elements, which you can append wherever you need to:

```
const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState([])

const results = useQueries(
  selection.map(item => ({
    queryKey: ['something', item]
    queryFn: () => fetchItem(item)
  })
)

const data = results.map(result => result.data)
```

Comment: Yes - that was also what i ended up with

Comment: Is it possible to have this wait on the previous call to finish before starting a new one? Lets say I have an array of 5 calls all the same endpoint but with a different ID, user/id/1, user/id/2 and so on.

Comment: sounds like dependent queries: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries